# Expression that returns a content between two DateTimes in a log file if a certain Token stayes in between

Tags: c#, regex

The log file can contain the following entries:

```
07.07.2014 00:03:11:701 - ERROR: bla-bla <MyToken>, Exception <bla-bla|bla-bla 

   at bla-bla|bla-bla
   at bla-bla|bla-bla
   at bla-bla|bla-bla
   at bla-bla|bla-bla
   at bla-bla|bla-bla
   at bla-bla|bla-bla
   at bla-bla|bla-bla
   at bla-bla|bla-bla
07.07.2014 00:03:19:029 - INFO 3:
```

for reading the content I am using the following expression:

```
@"(?<entry>[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{4}\s[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{3}\s-\s(.*\n?)(?=MyToken)(.*\n?))(?=([0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{4}\s[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{3}))"
```

the problem is that that I cannot get the **at bla-bla** rows when I am getting content of the entry group. Have tried to modify the rule to

```
@"(?<entry>[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{4}\s[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{3}\s-\s(.*\n?)(?=MyToken)(.*\n?)*)(?=([0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{4}\s[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{3}))"
```

but after than the application is dead.

And the reason I think that the `(.*\n?)*` is too generic.

What would be the right predicate or even what would be the better expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track that `(.*\n?)*` is the part that is causing trouble. When you use it, you are creating a very good scenario for the regex to do something called [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).

The fix for you might be to substitute this group with `[\s\S]*?` (`[\s\S]` will match every character, including newlines) or if you use `.*?` with the `SingleLine` flag (or the `(?s)` inline modifier):

```
@"(?<entry>[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{4}\s[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{3}\s-\s(.*\n?)(?=MyToken)([\s\S]*?))(?=([0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{4}\s[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{3}))"
```

or

```
@"(?<entry>[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{4}\s[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{3}\s-\s(.*\n?)(?=MyToken)(.*?))(?=([0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{4}\s[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{3}))", RegexOptions.SingleLine
```

Finally, if you only need one entry, you might convert the unnecessary capture groups into non-capture groups, or remove the capture groups if no groups are required (first version):

```
@"(?<entry>[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{4}\s[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{3}\s-\s.*\n?(?=MyToken)[\s\S]*?)(?=[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{4}\s[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{3})"
```

And if you want to make the above a little shorter, you might use something like...

```
@"(?<entry>(?:[0-9]{2}\.){2}[0-9]{4}\s(?:[0-9]{2}:){3}[0-9]{3}\s-\s.*\n?(?=MyToken)[\s\S]*?)(?=(?:[0-9]{2}\.){2}[0-9]{4}\s(?:[0-9]{2}:){3}[0-9]{3})"
```

Comment: Or better yet, don't use regex for this at all, or at least only for individual lines.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Yea. I would personally scan line by line and look for the 'key line' and when I get there, get in a state of 'capture' to get all lines until I reach the 'end mark'. Reading several lines at a go has never been my cup of tea.